# How to update a field that is a drop down list from another table using a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hey guys in my access database I have two tables labeled **'Contacts'** and **'StatusList'**.
 **StatusList** consists of one column and four rows labeled:

**StatusDescription**
Suspect
Prospect
Inquiry
Applicant

**Contacts** consists of the following:

First Last Email Status Phone

The Status field in Contacts is a drop down box that feeds of off the StatusList table. Every row in the Contacts table is set to Suspect initially.

The email field in Contacts is set to only allow unique emails.

I have a table labeled ExcelImport that has the same fields as the Contacts table.

Eventually, I want to insert the the data from my ExcelImport table to Contacts. If there is an email match between ExcelImport and Contacts, I want the row in Contacts for the Status field to be updated from Suspect to Prospect.

So far I have this:

```
SELECT Contacts.contactEmail
FROM Contacts
Inner Join ExcelImport on Contacts.contactEmail = ExcelImport.contactEmail;
```

I know this only shows me the emails that match. Would there be any way to update the Status list for that specific row that matched to Prospect ?

Comment: You need to use an Update "query", not a select query.  Also, the fact that the StatusList table is used to populate a dropdown list seems irrelevant since the actual question is about updating one table from another table with matching email fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, simply change the value with an `UPDATE` action query and the dropdown will change accordingly. The dropdown if I understand you is simply a lookup combox box that you possibly set in the *Table Design*. It simply helps control the values entered. The `UPDATE` query will change that dropdown as value of table changes:

```
UPDATE Contacts INNER JOIN ExcelImport 
    ON Contacts.contactEmail = ExcelImport.contactEmail
SET Contacts.[Status] = 'Prospect';
```

Additionally, you mention *I want to insert the the data from my ExcelImport table to Contacts* which you can do so preserving the uniqueness of the *Email* field by running a `NOT EXISTS` 
clause in append query.

```
INSERT INTO Contacts ([First], [Last], [Email]], [Status], [Phone])
SELECT e.[First], e.[Last], e.[Email]], e.[Status], e.[Phone]
FROM ExcelImport e
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM Contacts c WHERE c.[Email] = e.[Email])
```

Therefore, run both action queries to import unique *Email* and for repeated *Email*, update *Status*.